# how to parse .proto file into FileDescriptor in golang？

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

My goal is to get FileDescriptor from .proto file dynamically, how should I do it?

input:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package "halo";

message SearchRequest {
    string query = 1;
    string data = 2;
}
```

output:

```golang
import  "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/descriptorpb"

descriptorpb.FileDescriptorProto{
    Package: "halo",
    MessageType: []{
        descriptorpb.DescriptorProto{query},
        descriptorpb.DescriptorProto{data},
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless a platform-specific runtime/library parser exists for your platform, the simplest way to do this is to use `protoc` with the `-oFILE` / `--descriptor_set_out=FILE` option, which parses the schema and outputs a protobuf payload that is the serialized `FileDescriptorSet` contents. You would deserialize this in your specific platform, and take the first (usually only) file. For this deserialize step, you would typically use `protoc` with the [descriptor.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto) schema as input, to get a platform/language-specific parser for that schema.

Platform-specific runtime/library parsers aren't common, and tend to be more common in 3rd-party tooling; the Google golang protobuf implementation is 1st-party, and no such parser exists for golang AFAIK.